# Некорректное срабатывание таймера пробуждения Foreground Service

Tags: android, android-service

Други, доброго дня!

Есть `Service`, запускается при загрузке (ну вроде запускается), создаёт при старте задачу (на самом деле несколько, но суть у них одна).  Задача что-то делает и на какое то время засыпает таким образом:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(180);
```

Вроде как все бы и хорошо, НО, например, вот крайний раз после запуска задача впервые отработала чуть ли не через час! Ну это как так-то? Делал перед этим через таймер, примерно так:

```
TT = new myTimerTask();
T2 = new Timer();
if (TT != null && T2 != null)
T2.scheduleAtFixedRate(TT, 1000, 1000*60); //-- раз в минуту
```

Работало аналогично как попало: то 20 раз в сек, то через 10 минут. Вот переделал на задачи — похожая фигня. То соблюдается интервал, то как попало. В чём могут быть причины?

Сам `Service` во время спячки телефона висит как `Foreground`, а когда тело просыпается, выходит из `Foreground` (заказчика раздражает постоянно висящий значок приложения из-за `Foreground`, вот и извращаюсь).

Сейчас вот смотрю по логам — задача отработала только при создании `Service`, прошло 25 минут - запусков больше не было (через 5 минут должны быть). Записи в логе о достижении `onDestroy()` `Service`'а — нет. Или он просто молча прибит ОС?

Стартовать `Service` при каждом выключении экрана что ли?

====== Дополнение, (почти) весь код Сервиса =============

```
public class LockscreenService extends Service
    implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private Thread T   = null;

    WindowManager windowManager;
    TextView alertText;
    boolean removed;

    boolean iam_set_bg;
    static boolean iam_started = false;

    int NOTIFY_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Config.log("LSS Created");


        if (Config.st == null)
                Config.st = new StorageInterface(this);
            else
                Config.st.link(this);

            iam_set_bg=false;
    }


    // Register for Lockscreen event intents
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("LSS", "Service started 1");
        if (!iam_started)
        {
            iam_started = true;


            if (T==null)
                T = new Thread( new splasher() ); //-- поток показывающий вспышку
            if (T!=null)
                T.start();


            Log.d("LSS", "Threads started.");

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            filter.addAction(LockscreenIntentReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION_NOTE);
            filter.addAction(LockscreenIntentReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION_ADV);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED);
            mReceiver = new LockscreenIntentReceiver();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


            SensorManager mySensorManager =
                (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

            Sensor LightSensor = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
            if(LightSensor != null)
                {
//               Log.d("LSS", "Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT Available");
                     mySensorManager.registerListener(
                         this,
                         LightSensor,
                         SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
            else
            {
//              Log.d("LSS", "Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT NOT Available");
                    Config.light = 0;
            }

                windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                alertText = new TextView(this);
                alertText.setOnClickListener(this);
                alertText.setBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor("#666666") );
                alertText.setTextColor( Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                alertText.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                alertText.setTextSize(22);
                removed = true;

            Log.d("LSS", "Inintialized...");

        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("LSS", "Get CMD");

            if (intent.hasExtra("act"))
            {
                int act = intent.getIntExtra("act", 0);

                if (act == 1)
                {
                    Config.log("# startForeground");
                    startForeground();
                }
                if (act == 2)
                {
                    Config.log("# stopForeground");
                    this.stopForeground( true );
                }
                if (act == 3)
                    this.hint("Виберите НЕТ для отключения штатной блокировки");
                if (act == 4)
                {
                    if (!removed)
                        windowManager.removeView(alertText);
                    removed = true;

                }           

            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    // Run service in foreground so it is less likely to be killed by system
    private void startForeground() {
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
         .setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
         .setContentText("Running")
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setContentIntent(null)
         .setOngoing(true)
         .build();
         startForeground(9999, notification);       
    }

    // Unregister receiver
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Config.log("LSS Destroyed");

        if (T != null)
        {
            Thread dummy = T;
            T = null;
            dummy.interrupt();
        }

        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    public class splasher implements Runnable
    {
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
         Log.d("LSS TASK", "RUN started");
         while(true)
         {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(180);
                     Log.d("LSS TASK", "RUN show : Config.screen_off=" +
                         Config.screen_off);

                     Config.log("Flash: light=" + onfig.light + " activ=" +
                         Config.curr_active[30] + " set=" + Config.curr_sets[30]);

                     if (Config.locked == 1 &&
                         Config.screen_off == 1 &&
                         Config.inring == 0 &&
                         Config.incall == 0 && 
                         Config.light > 20) 
                     {
                         Config.adv = 1;

                         Intent intent =
                             new Intent(LockscreenIntentReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION_ADV);

                         intent.putExtra("act", 5);
                         sendBroadcast(intent);
                     }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }
     }


    }
//--------------- /splasher --------


    //---- light sensor---

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
    {
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {

            // TODO
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
        {
            if (event.values[0] <= 0)
                return;
            Config.light = event.values[0];
        }
    }

    public void hint( String str )
    {
        alertText.setText( str );
        alertText.setOnClickListener(this);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
//        params.x = 0;
//        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(alertText, params);
        removed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!removed)
            windowManager.removeView(alertText);
        removed = true;
    }
}
```

Если это поможет...

`Service` дёргается каждый раз при выключении и включении экрана. Т.е. регулярно имеет возможность перезапуститься, но в логах нет следов перезапуска, т.е. он значит жив и здоров. Но логи запуска задачи - то есть, то нет. Причём бывает, что логи смены освещения есть, а запуска задачи, который должен произойти в это же время — нету... 
Чего-то я не недопонимаю.

Comment: скинь код полностью

Comment: добавил код сервиса

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант с использованием **ScheduledExecutorService**

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (true) {
        // Запускается сбор статистики
        Log.v("Tracking", "logging");

        } else {
            // scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
            // Отключение сбора статистики
        }
    }
}, 1, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
// Закончили основную работу, далее сработает через 1 минуту,
// потом всё время будет срабатывать каждые 5 минут.
```